# Question about pattern of lightning:input

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightninginput

how i can have a field (lightning:input) in which i can write 3 integer and 3 decimal? Something like 123.456 (max 3 integer and max 3 decimal, with "." or "," between integer and decimal). I try to use the attribute pattern, but i don't have good results.
Thanks for help in advice

Comment: When you say 3 integers and 3 decimals, do you mean one number formatted like this?

Comment: yes, a number formatted like 123.456 or 12.345 or 12,3 etc...

Comment: You should probably use the [ui:inputNumber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputNumber.htm) instead of the lightning:input. And specify a format on the specific attribute.

Comment: i was order to use lightnint:input :/

Comment: I would not use `ui:inputNumber` as it has been deprecated by Salesforce.

Answer (score -1):

Try this pattern,

```
^([1-9]{0,1})([1-9]{0,1})([0-9]{1})((\.[0-9]{0,1})([0-9]{1})|(\,[0-9]{0,1})([0-9]{1}))(([0-9]{1}))?$
```

Comment: This pattern doesn't work for numbers like "100". How about `^\d{1,3}(?:(\.|\,)\d{1,3})?$`? It's much less verbose.